# Masked Input: remove hyphen from number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I'm using Masked Input plugin for jQuery in my form this way:

```
$('#phone').mask("9999-9999");
```

Then, all the form is `serialize` and send to a PHP file using AJAX.

The problem is I need to remove the hyphen from the phone number. I try this:

```
$('#phone').mask("9999-9999").bind("blur", function(){
    var myStr = $(this).val();
    myStr=myStr.replace(/\-/g,'');
    $(this).val(myStr);
});
```

But I would like to remove the hyphen only in the value that is sent.

Comment: Remove it in the PHP code?

Comment: @AndyHolmes PHP recieve the form serialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove the hyphen when you send the phone number to the PHP script, can't you simply do it in your PHP code or when sending your Ajax request? E.g. (second solution)

```
function sendAjax() {
    var telNumber = $('#phone').val();
    telNumber = telNumber.replace(/\-/g,'');
    $.post('/your-script.php', ...)
}

$('#submitbutton').click(sendAjax);
```

Comment: I'm sending form values serialized to PHP

Comment: @AndyHolmes Update the string?

Comment: Just because a form is serialised shouldn't stop you from altering the data inside the PHP file. Seeing that file would help though